# Toggle Light Switch - Two Lights, One Electrical Source

Tags: lighting, switch

I want to create/buy a switch like this:

[image]

(this is a two wheeler turn indicator switch)

My needs:

1. I've got one electrical source
2. If I move the switch to the **left** side, then the **left bulb
   should glow** and if its on the **right**, then **right bulb should
   glow.**
3. If the switch is in the **central** position, then both the **lights
   should be off**

My doubts:

- What's the name of this kind of electrical switch for household use?
- How can I wire this?

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, your first "doubt" tho gives us the clue tho that you want the "functionality" in a switch styled different than what you have pictured.

Google "SPDT Center Off switch", it's available in many form factors and styles, including "wall switch" or household type.   (Avoid "momentary" in the description, those will 'spring' back to center rather than stay maintained On in one position or the other--I mention this only because Google search suggestions try to force me into the 'momentary' switches.)

(SPDT = Single Pole Double Throw)

[image: Single Pole Single Throw Center OFF switch for household use.]

Comment: Thanks. Got it: http://www.amazon.in/Toggle-Switch-SPDT-Center-250V/dp/B01DEWK8I4 I just want to connect 2 light bulbs from a single electrical source. Can you please help with the wiring?